# Why should avoid use SCP with sudo

Tags: command-line, sudo, scp

Can Please anyone explains to me why should avoid using `sudo` when used `scp`. I'll send a File from my Host to another Host, forward a time I to ready that best use `scp` without `sudo`, then later avoid problem....

Very thanks!

Comment: Please expand the question. It is totally unclear now. Is the question Ubuntu related? What are you doing with SCP? Why would  you use SCP with sudo? Who told you that you should avoid it? Please [edit] your question.

Comment: Who says that you should avoid that ? If you have to copy files you don't have access rights to, you need elevated privileges, and sudo is one way to get that. THe problem is off course that if you receive files with `sudo scp ...` you can overwrite important files on your system ... but that's what come with elevated privileges.

Comment: Tanks for your answer!, I don't Understand `but that's what comes with elevated privileges` , on my destination host?